# How to pass parameter/arguments to functions in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

First, I'm just getting started with node js (look at the question), so please bear with me

This is a case I made to make my question clearer. I made a function to be called on another JS :

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `test`', function (error, results) {
  console.log(results);
  });
};
```

Then I can call it with `object.test();`

I want to generalize this function, by passing the table name from another JS, instead of hardcoding it. *How to do that?*

In Java, I could googling about this easily. However, on Node, almost all search results telling about the parameter in the url (POST/GET), but my need is to just passing a param/args to a function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just pass it in the function's arguments, like `object.test(req, res, tableName)` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille: He/she probably wants to use the result with Express-style middleware, which will call the function with `req, res`.

Comment: They can attach the tablename to `req` then. `req.tableName="test"`

Comment: @JeremyThille: Those come from Express, not the OP's code. It would be possible to insert *another* middleware function that added properties to `req`, but I wouldn't consider it good design, not least because of potential conflict. Building a function with baked-in info like this is entirely standard practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a Node question, it's a JavaScript question.

You can create a function that returns a function. You pass the table name to the builder, and then use it in the function that builder creates:

```
exports.makeTest = function(tableName) {
  return function test(req, res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `' + tableName + '`', function (error, results) {
      console.log(results);
    });
  };
};
```

**Note:** I assume `tableName` comes from code you control and can trust; otherwise, string concatenation is not acceptable in the above.

You'd use it like this:

```
var test = makeTest("test");
```

...and then call `test` with `req` and `res` (or more likely, pass it to something like Express that will).

Here's a non-Node example just to show how the parts work:

```js
function makeTest(tableName) {
  return function test(req, res) {
    console.log("Table name is:", tableName);
    console.log("req is:", req);
    console.log("res is:", res);
  };
}

var test = makeTest("test");
console.log("Call 1:");
test({name: "req1"}, {name: "res1"});
console.log("Call 2:");
test({name: "req2"}, {name: "res2"});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

It may seem surprising that the `tableName` argument is still accessible to the `test` function after `makeTest` returns. That's the nature of JavaScript's *closures*. You can read more about closures here:

- [*How do JavaScript closures work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) - question with answers here on SO
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) - a post on my anemic little blog

Comment: Very interesting, I will reuse that in future developments.

Comment: Could you please explain `or more likely, pass it to something like Express that will`? I don't really get how to "pass it to Express"

Comment: @JeremyThille: Express has you call functions to register handlers for routes in your web server ([example here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)): After defining your "app" (an HTTP server listening on a given address and port), you call (for instance) `get` to set up a handler for GET requests. For instance, the root route: `app.get("/", ...)`. That's what you pass the function to: `app.get("/", test)`. Then Express calls that function when a request for that route is received, passing it the `req` (request) and `res` (response) objects.

Comment: *(cont'd)* There I've used `test` (the variable created in my answer), but more likely in this case you'd just pass the result of calling `makeTest("test")` (the function it creates) directly into `get`: `app.get("/", makeTest("test"))`. Now, I'm just guessing based on the `(req, res)` parameter list that the OP is using Express; they may well not be, but they're likely to be using *something* where they pass the function to it and it, rather than their own code, calls the function with a set argument list.

Comment: Interesting, I think I'm getting it. But how to pass a variable to `makeTest`, instead of `"test"`? Where would this variable come from? Edit : I think it could be from the route : `app.get("/:tableName", makeTest(req.params.tableName))`, right? Makes sense.

Comment: @JeremyThille: You'd pass it just like passing any other variable to a function; its *value* (not the variable) would be passed. It could come from any scope accessible where the `makeTest(...)` call is (e.g., the current scope, or any containing scope).

Comment: Yep I got that, I was just wondering how to pass the variable to the router. Previous comment edited. Thanks, that helped :)

Comment: @JeremyThille: No, in your `app.get("/:tableName", makeTest(req.params.tableName))` example, `makeTest` is called **before** `app.get` is called (think `foo(bar())`, it's exactly the same), and *long* before Express calls the handler in response to a GET. You access route parameters **inside** the handler (the function `makeTest` *returns*), via the `req.params` object passed to it ([example](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req)).

Comment: Ah right, if I go `makeTest(req.params.tableName)`, I may get `req is undefined` or something. Uuuuuuh I'll give this some thought.

Comment: @JeremyThille: You'd get an error because `req` is an undeclared identifier in that scope. :-) Yeah, if you're interested in Express, play around with it a bit and you'll get it.

Comment: To my shame, I must confess that I've been using Express and its router for a long while, and I only use Node and Express for my apps's back-end. But I never thought about this function-builder function and how to call it, I'll try and get better at it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the concept of Higher order function in this

```
module.exports = function(tableName) {
  return function(req, res) {
    //...here you have tableName accessible
  };
};
```

And in the routes (if you're following the general flow of express app) where you are applying this controller,

```
const somethingController = require('/path/to/file');
route.get('/something', somethinController('test')); //...pass the table Name
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are multiple points here.

Firstly, your `test` function takes two parameters - a `req` and a `res`. Assuming you're using `express` to create a HTTP server this symbolises the incoming request and the outbound response. So I would read up on how express attaches things like `POST` data or query parameters in order to allow you to pass dynamic data into a route handler.

Secondly, you can interpolate strings in Javascript with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). For instance:

```
`select * from ${myTableParameter}`
```